# How to split a numeric string and then store it in an int array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string, strtok

I want to split a numeric string into separate numbers and then store each number in an integer array. 
For example we have this numeric string: `1 2 3` and I want the output to be:

```
arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = 3
```

I am using the strtok() function.
However , the code below does not display the expected results:

```
int main()
{
    char b[] = "1 2 3 4 5";
    char *p = strtok(b," ");
    int init_size = strlen(b);
    int arr[init_size];
    int i = 0;

    while( p != NULL)
    {
       arr[i++] = p;
       p = strtok(NULL," ");
    }

    for(i = 0; i < init_size; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert string to int using `strtol` for example:

```
   char *p = strtok(b," ");
    while( p != NULL)
    {
       arr[i++] = strtol(p, NULL, 10); // arr[i++] = p is wrong, because p is a string not an integer value
       p = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
```

When you print the value of array, use `%d` for integer value instead of `%s`. You use `init_size` is wrong. Because in the string, it has some space character. Your printing part should change to:

```
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("%d\n", arr[j]);
```

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char b[] = "1 2 3 4 5";
    int init_size = strlen(b);
    int arr[init_size];
    int i = 0;

    char *p = strtok(b," ");
    while( p != NULL)
    {
       arr[i++] = strtol(p, NULL, 10);
       p = strtok(NULL," ");
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("%d\n", arr[j]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering, however I get a warning saying "assignment makes pointer from integer without cast" for ```arr[i++] = strtol(p,NULL,10); and format '%d' exepects argument of type int" and wants me to use %ls at the printing part

Comment: Try to use `arr[i++] = (int ) strtol(p, NULL, 10);`

Comment: `strtol` return long int type. You can use `atoi(p)` instead of `strtol` (it's depreciated), or use the cast as the comment above.

Comment: @user47 try to copy and paste my code, because i do not see any warning. If you have still the warning, use other solution as the comment above.

Comment: thank you so much, however, now it only prints number 1 nonstop :(

Comment: @user47 It's not possible. Try the online compiler https://onlinegdb.com/ryljijAR5U . Did you copy and paste correctly my code ?